Why is spring boot app not able to find ServerHttpSecurity bean?
I have the class,
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.net.URI;

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                exchanges
                    .pathMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers("/sinke-resources").authenticated()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                oauth2Login
                    .authenticationSuccessHandler((webFilterExchange, authentication) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse()
                                .getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/sinke-resources")))
                                .then())
                    .authenticationFailureHandler((webFilterExchange, exception) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse()
                                .getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/failed-auth")))
                                .then())
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


When i start the application i get the message,
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method securityWebFilterChain in org.sinke.oauth2.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' in your configuration.


I read from text
and did the deleted @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity and added @EnableWebFluxSecurity
so my code became,

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                exchanges
                    .pathMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers("/sinke-resources").authenticated()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                oauth2Login
                    .authenticationSuccessHandler((webFilterExchange, authentication) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse()
                                .getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/sinke-resources")))
                                .then())
                    .authenticationFailureHandler((webFilterExchange, exception) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                            webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse()
                                .getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/failed-auth")))
                                .then())
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


and i had the error,
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true


Why I am doing wrong?
